# django.db.utils.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'qd_project_assist.id' in 'field list'")

Tags: django

```
class QdProjectAssist(models.Model):
    project_id = models.ForeignKey('QdProject', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assist_id = models.ForeignKey('QdAssist', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sort = models.PositiveIntegerField('排序', blank=True, null=True)
    add_time = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    uptime = models.DateTimeField( auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'project_assist'
        unique_together = ('project_id', 'assist_id')
```

I export the table with two primary keys from mysql.

Reporting errors in the course of use:

```
django.db.utils.InternalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'qd_project_assist.id' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: have you run migration for `QdProject`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a dev environment try delete all tables and run `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: I can't delete the tables in the database, only use the existing table structure in the Django project.